# Webscraper using Python does not return any error, but also doesn't work

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, automation

I would like to know if something similar alredy happened with you and what you did to solve this problem. When I and other coleagues run the code it simply doens't show any error, only doing the automatized search, but seeming to ignore all the rest.

1. Firts I imported the necessary packages

```
import selenium
import time
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
```

2. Then I created the webdriver to use with selenium

```
from selenium import webdriver
from msedge.selenium_tools import EdgeOptions
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

edge_driver_path = 'C:/Users/IIIIIINGRID/OneDrive/Área de Trabalho/projetoretorica/edgedriver_win64/msedgedriver.exe'

driver = webdriver.Edge(executable_path=edge_driver_path)
```

3. I programmed an automatized search in the website below and then iterad it

```
driver.get('https://www.camara.leg.br/internet/sitaqweb/pesquisaDiscursos.asp')

termos_de_pesquisa = ["Nikolas Ferreira", "Rosângela Moro", "Zé Neto", "Alice Portugal", "Sidney Leite", "Silvia Waiãpi",
                         "Erika Kokay", "Geraldo Resende", "Marcel Van Hattem", "Fernanda Melchionna"]

#iteration

for termo in termos_de_pesquisa:
   
    pesquisa=driver.find_element_by_name("txOrador")
    pesquisa.clear()
    pesquisa.send_keys(termo)
    pesquisa.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
    time.sleep(60)
    driver.back()
```

4. to identify and click on the HTML link that correspond to the speech classified as "Breve Comunicações" ("Brief Comunications)

```
    discurso_link = None
   
    try:
        fases = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="content"]/div/table/tbody/tr/td[3]')
   
        for fase in fases:
           
            if 'BREVES COMUNICAÇÕES' in fase.text:
               
                discurso_link = fase.find_elements(By.XPATH, '.following-sibling::td[4]/a')
               
                discurso_link.click()
               
                print("Link do discurso clicado com sucesso!")
            else:
                print("Fase não corresponde a breves comunicações!")
```

5. Last but not least, the scraper per si (when the conditions above are confirmed)

```
        if discurso_link:
            site = requests.get(discurso_link.get_attribute("href"))
            soup = BeautifulSoup(site.content, 'html.parser')
```

6. So that the program get only the speech content

```
            def encontrar_indice_ocorrencia(discurso, caractere, ocorrencia):
                contador = 0
                for indice, char in enumerate(discurso):
                    if char == caractere:
                        contador += 1
                        if contador == ocorrencia:
                            return indice
                return -1
       
            discurso = soup.find('p').get_text()
            caractere = "-"
            segunda_ocorrencia = encontrar_indice_ocorrencia(discurso, caractere, 2)
         
            # output do discurso

            print(discurso[segunda_ocorrencia:])

    except NoSuchElementException:
        print("Link do discurso não encontrado!")

driver.quit()
```

I tried a lot of things, because first I thought the problem was in the html location of the data I was trying to scrape, but I fixed that and nothing. The indentation also seems correct. I honestly would say it's an error of understanding of the functions function, like, the way I putted or again because of some html structure of the website, it just did not understood what I was trying to do, without finding any formal error in the code. There's the six steps I took (some things are going to be in portuguese, because that's my native language and scope of that specific project):

Probably there's lots of erros in this, I don't really know to program and this code was made using the help, if you could say that, of ChatGPT. My curiosity behond what I did not well compreehend in this code structure and interpretation/semantics is why it do not show any errors, but also do not do what I hoped. Alredy recommended me to use wait function, but I would love to get more insights if possible.

Comment: too much code, please reduce to this:
[minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this example how to get the text of the speeches:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

api_url = "https://www.camara.leg.br/internet/sitaqweb/resultadoPesquisaDiscursos.asp"

params = {
    "txOrador": "Nikolas Ferreira",  # <-- change the name here
    "CurrentPage": 1,                # <-- increase the pages here
    "txPartido": "",
    "txUF": "",
    "dtInicio": "",
    "dtFim": "",
    "txTexto": "",
    "txSumario": "",
    "basePesq": "plenario",
    "CampoOrdenacao": "dtSessao",
    "PageSize": "50",
    "TipoOrdenacao": "DESC",
    "btnPesq": "Pesquisar",
}

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(api_url, params=params).content, "html.parser")

for row in soup.select("tr"):
    tds = [td.get_text(strip=True) for td in row.select("td")]
    if len(tds) > 2 and tds[2] == "BREVES COMUNICAÇÕES":
        u = "https://www.camara.leg.br/internet/sitaqweb/" + row.a["href"]
        u = u.replace("\r", "").replace("\n", "").replace("\t", "")
        html_text = requests.get(u).text
        soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(u).content, "html.parser")
        print(soup.p.text)
        print("-" * 80)
```

Prints:

```
O SR. NIKOLAS FERREIRA (PL - MG. Sem revisão do orador.) - Obrigado, Sr. Presidente. Eu quero dizer ao povo brasileiro que é mentira que essa reforma está sendo discutida há 20 anos. Na verdade, ela tem sido des
ejada há 20 anos. Essa reforma de hoje está sendo discutida há uma semana. Não há Relator. Pelo contrário, houve somente um Grupo de Trabalho, cujo Presidente é um petista. Ou seja, você não faz uma reforma nem 
na sua casa de um dia para o outro, e eles querem colocar aqui a discussão em um dia e a votação dessa reforma no outro dia. Eu pergunto: em que você, brasileiro, vai ser impactado com esta reforma? Em primeiro 
lugar, a Associação Brasileira de Supermercados disse, em uma pesquisa, que irá aumentar em 60%, em média, o preço da sua cesta básica. A sua, trabalhador, que acorda cedo. Não vai aumentar para o Lula e para a 
Janja, não; o aumento vai ser para você.  E com relação à atual reforma, nós temos a composição do Conselho Tributário, que é completamente desproporcional, uma vez que há Estados, como Minas Gerais, que contrib
ui com 10% para o PIB brasileiro; e São Paulo, que, somente a capital, também contribui com 10%, tendo o mesmo peso dos demais Estados. E aí eu pergunto: tem que existir um fundo de desenvolvimento regional some
nte para o Nordeste, Centro-Oeste e Norte? O Sul e o Sudeste ficam de lado? Não há pessoas pobres em Minas Gerais? Não há pessoas passando dificuldade no nosso Estado? Eu quero dizer que não sou Mãe Dináh, não s
ou futurologista, mas o "imposto do pecado" será usado por Marina Silva, por ecoterroristas para taxar o agronegócio, para acabar com a locomotiva do nosso País. Eu tenho aqui — Deputada Júlia, por favor, se pud
er, pegue aqueles papéis ali para mim — material que mostra algumas coincidências. Hoje — logo hoje, no dia em que vai ser votado isso —, houve uma liberação de emendas pelo Presidente Lula, que antigamente cham
ava isso de orçamento secreto, de 2,1 bilhão de reais. Eu pergunto: será que essa liberação tem alguma coisa a ver com a votação da reforma, Deputado Pr. Marco Feliciano? Será que tem alguma coisa a ver?  Dê só 
uma olhada em quem antes era contrário a esse tipo de emenda: Erika Hilton, que dizia: "orçamento secreto, não". Fabiano Contarato dizia que o orçamento secreto era bolsolão. Olhem quem está aqui, se não é ele, 
Lula, dizendo que "o orçamento secreto é a excrescência da política brasileira". Sâmia Bomfim: "orçamento secreto, não". Randolfe Rodrigues também era contrário. Felipe Neto também era contrário. O "Pastor da Sh
opee" também era contrário. Talíria Petrone também era contrária. Jandira Feghali também era contrária. O mentiroso Janones também era contrário. Simone Tebet também. Gleisi Hoffmann e o mentiroso do Guga Noblat
, todos eles, contrários. Para concluir, Presidente, todos eles eram contrários ao então orçamento secreto. Agora já não é mais orçamento secreto. Agora é orçamento do bem. Mas, graças a Deus — graças a Deus! —,
 o amor venceu, e nós não temos mais problema nenhum. Mas ninguém disse que esse amor seria sofrido. Ninguém disse que esse amor seria doloroso. Quando a cesta básica aumentar, não vai haver impressão digital mi
nha em um projeto que vai trazer mais pobreza para o nosso País.  Obrigado, Presidente.  
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
O SR. NIKOLAS FERREIRA (PL - MG. Sem revisão do orador.) - Boa tarde, Presidente. Quero dizer ao povo brasileiro que o pobre foi usado, o pobre foi enganado. Anteriormente, foi prometida picanha, entregaram abób
ora, mas não para por aí. Basicamente estão fazendo uma reforma tributária que, na verdade, é uma reforma da fome, porque haverá um aumento, em média, de 60% na cesta básica, e não nos alimentos que o Lula come 
no Palácio da Alvorada.  Inclusive, Deputado Gustavo Gayer, ele disse que lá os alimentos são ruins, não são iguais aos da casa dele, menosprezando o que ele come lá no Palácio da Alvorada. Na cidade de São Paul
o, o preço médio da cesta básica é de 782 reais e vai para 1.212 reais. Basicamente, você aí, trabalhador, que ouviu na eleição que, se o Lula ganhasse, teria cervejinha, teria picanha, vai ter que trabalhar o m
ês inteiro para conseguir comprar uma cesta básica caso a reforma da fome passe! Em Belo Horizonte, onde a cesta básica chega a 707 reais, o aumento vai ser de 55%, ou seja, vão ser necessários mais mil reais pa
ra se comprar uma cesta básica lá. O que quero dizer aqui? Que, enquanto o Lula e a Janja ficam viajando pelo País, comendo nos melhores restaurantes, você aí, pobre, trabalhador, cidadão comum que acorda cedo p
ara poder sustentar a sua casa, basicamente está sendo enganado. Eu quero inclusive saber quando o Lula, que visita todos os países, vai visitar o Brasil. Quando o Lula, de fato, vai visitar o nosso País para to
mar conta da nossa Nação? Eu quero dizer que nós somos contra a reforma da fome, uma reforma que aumenta impostos, que retira as atribuições dos Municípios e que nada mais faz do que colocar, sim, o pobre no orç
amento, mas não de uma forma boa, e sim fazendo com que ele pague com seu dinheiro por esse orçamento, deixando o Lula cada vez mais rico, a União cada vez mais rica. Para finalizar, Sr. Presidente, quero dizer 
que ontem eu tive que ouvir aqui diversas acusações aos cristãos. Eu quero dizer que nós não vamos mais aguentar rótulos de fascistas, homofóbicos, genocidas e não vamos mais aceitar que coloquem os cristãos do 
Brasil como se fossem criminosos. Já fizeram isso em anos passados, tentando despersonificar, desumanizar os cristãos. Se daqui a pouco os cristãos forem retirados do Brasil, ninguém mais ligará, afinal de conta
s, o que se prega aqui é que essas pessoas são ruins. Deixo aqui o meu apoio a todos os cristãos deste Brasil! E digo: nós vamos resistir e não há nada que nos pare! 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

...and so on.
```

Comment: Thank you a lot, Andrej. It was super helpful and I'm definetly going to learn and use it in my research. If I'm not asking much, I wanted to know if it's possible to automatize the creation of strings vectors with each of these speeches once I need them to be in that format. That way, It's possible for me to translate them to english and then transform them with a text-to-image AI API. Thanks again!